# How do I properly store encoded characters in strings.xml?

Tags: android, string, character-encoding, carriage-return

I am trying to store two carriage returns in in strings.xml but can't figure out why they are ignored. However, if I put them directly into the layout, the carriage returns work fine.

**Outputs carriage returns**
`android:text="&#xA;&#xA;Sent from my wonderful Android device"`

**Does not output carriage returns**
`<string name="sent_from">&#xA;&#xA;Sent from my wonderful Android device</string>`

Comment: Try using Html.fromHtml to get the string in your code. That should have the carriage returns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<string name="sent_from">\n\nSent from my wonderful Android device</string>
```

I think that is what you are looking for.